# How to determine pinout on proprietary 3-pin charging port?

Tags: charger, pinout

I picked up a dog collar at a yard sale that didn't come with a charger. Looks to use a 3pin charge port which takes 12v. Don't really want to buy a special charger for just 12v so was wondering how to determine what the pinout might be to make one for myself. I would just open the unit to look at the board, but don't want to break the waterproof seal for the device unless necessary. Thanks!

[Picture of port](https://imgur.com/a/bVjwoqw)

[Link to ebay listing for charger](https://www.ebay.com/itm/235181186090)

Comment: why would a dog collar require a charger?

Comment: Determining pinout is one thing. Determining if the charger is really a charger or just a power supply is another thing, which likely can't be determined without opening the device.

Comment: @jsotola: it's for a shock collar, illegal in Europe and some other jurisdictions because using one is considered to be animal cruelty there.

Comment: If it's an ultrasonic collar for insect/parasite infections, it'll work just as well whether it's charged or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up opening it. Counting pins up from middle to outside (1,2,3):

1 = G
2 = +12v
3 = NC

Works just fine with straight 12v. Nothing fancy.